# Making a 16-bit ALU using 1-bit ALUs

Tags: vhdl, alu

Hello I am trying to create a 16-bit ALU from several 1-bit ALUs 
I created a package named basic_alu1 which contains a component of the 1-bit ALU.The code for this is:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
package basic_alu1 is
component alu1
    port (a, b: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
            m: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
            result: out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0));
end component;
end package basic_alu1;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity alu1 is
    port (a, b: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    m: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    result: out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0));
end alu1; 
architecture arch1 of alu1 is 
begin
 process(a, b, m)
 begin
 case m is
 when "00" =>
    result <= a + b;
  when "01" =>
    result <= a + (not b) + 1;
  when "10" =>
    result <= a and b;
  when "11" =>
    result <= a or b;
end case
 end process
 end arch1
```

So, in order to create the 16 bit ALU I am using a for generate loop and instantiate multiple copies of alu1. My question is how can I take the counter in and counter out and how can I have an overflow check. My main code is :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.basic_alu1.all;

entity alu16 is
  port (input_a : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        input_b : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        mode : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
        result_x4 : out std_logic);
end alu16;

architecture structural of alu16 is
begin
G1 : for i in 0 to 15 generate
begin
    alu_16 : entity work.basic_alu1
    port map (
    a => input_a(i),
    b => input_b(i),
    m => mode,
    result => result_x4(i));
end generate;
```

Comment: This is a _half adder_: `result <= a + b;`. You're going to need a _full adder_ (with a _carry in_ and a _carry out_): `(cout, result) <= a + b + ('0'&cin);` You then nned to daisy chain the carries: each carry in is driven by the carry out from the previous (lesser significant) stage. You can then detect overflow by comparing the two left hand bits of the 17-bit output (carry out of the MSB and the 16 other results). If those two bits are different, you have overflow.

Comment: Your code isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). it also has various syntax errors and your question is unclear - ***What counter?*** And as Matthew notes you are not constructing a 16 bit ALU without a carry chain. Besides a boatload of missing semicolons, a missing end statement, result_x4 declared as a single std_logic, and the missing case others choice, there isn't a "+" operator overload for adding an abstract literal to a std_logic value. Why are you trying to construct a 16 bit ALU from 1 bit ALUs? Is this a class assignment?

Comment: Charles Steinkuehler's answer ([vhdl - Making a 4-bit ALU from several 1-bit ALUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025962/making-a-4-bit-alu-from-several-1-bit-alus/4026534#4026534)) mentions "Ignoring the carry issue for the moment, you would typically just setup a for generate loop and instantiate multiple copies of your bitwise logic, possibly special casing the first and/or last elements", warning the reader carry was not covered and he showed `result_x4(bitindex) )` a selected name implying result_x4 is an array value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can create a N-bit adder component. First of all you need to create a full adder which is a adder that also takes a carry in bit into account.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY fullAdder IS
    PORT (a     : IN STD_LOGIC;
          b     : IN STD_LOGIC;
          cin   : IN STD_LOGIC;
          y     : OUT STD_LOGIC;
          cout  : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END fullAdder;

ARCHITECTURE arch_fullAdder OF fullAdder IS
BEGIN
    y <= a XOR b XOR cin;
    cout <= (a AND b) OR 
            (b AND cin) OR 
            (a AND cin);
END arch_fullAdder;
```

When you have this 1-bit adder you can easily generate a N-bit ripple carry by generating multiple cells of the full adder we have above.

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

ENTITY ripple_adder IS 
    GENERIC (WIDTH : NATURAL := 32);
    PORT(a      : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0);
         b      : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0);
         cin    : IN STD_LOGIC := '0';
         y      : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0);
         cout   : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END ripple_adder;

ARCHITECTURE arch_ripple_adder OF ripple_adder IS

    SIGNAL carry    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL y_temp   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0);

    COMPONENT fullAdder IS
        PORT(a      : IN STD_LOGIC;
             b      : IN STD_LOGIC;
             cin    : IN STD_LOGIC;
             y      : OUT STD_LOGIC;
             cout   : OUT STD_LOGIC);
    END COMPONENT;
BEGIN  

    N_bit_adder_generate : FOR N IN 0 TO WIDTH-1 GENERATE
    N_bit_adder : fullAdder
        PORT MAP(a      => a(N),
                 b      => b (N),
                 cin    => carry(N),
                 y      => y_temp(N),
                 cout   => carry(N + 1));
    END GENERATE;

    carry(0) <= cin;
    cout <= carry(WIDTH);
    y <= y_temp;

END arch_ripple_adder;
```

When you have the adder you can easily put the adder component into an ALU and specify the different operations that the ALU should be able to perform.

```
LIBRARY  ieee;
USE  ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY ALU IS 
    GENERIC(WIDTH : NATURAL := 32);
    PORT(Clk    : IN STD_LOGIC := '0';
         Reset  : IN STD_LOGIC := '0';
         A      : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
         B      : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
         Op     : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
         Outs   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0));
END ALU;

ARCHITECTURE arch_ALU OF ALU IS

    COMPONENT ripple_adder
    PORT(a      : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0);
         b      : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0);
         cin    : IN STD_LOGIC := '0';
         y      : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0);
         cout   : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT;

    SIGNAL RCA_output   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
    SIGNAL B_neg        : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
    SIGNAL c_flag       : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    SIGNAL c_reg        : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    SIGNAL cin          : STD_LOGIC := '0';

BEGIN

RCA_comp : ripple_adder
   PORT MAP(a => A,
            b => B_neg,
            Cin => cin,
            y => RCA_output,
            Cout => c_flag);        

    WITH Op SELECT 
        B_neg <= NOT(B) WHEN "1000",
                     B  WHEN OTHERS;

    WITH Op SELECT
        cin <= '1'      WHEN "1000", -- SUB
                c_reg   WHEN "0111", -- ADDC
                '0'     WHEN OTHERS; -- ADD/ADDS    

    ALU_Process:
    PROCESS(Clk, Reset)
    BEGIN
        IF Reset = '0' THEN
            Outs <= (OTHERS => '0');
            c_reg <= '0';
        ELSIF rising_edge(Clk) THEN
            CASE Op IS
                WHEN "0001" => Outs <= A AND B;
                WHEN "0010" => Outs <= A OR  B;
                WHEN "0011" => Outs <= A NOR B;
                WHEN "0100" => Outs <= A XOR B;
                WHEN "0101" => Outs <= RCA_output; -- ADD 
                WHEN "0110" => Outs <= RCA_output; -- ADDS
                    c_reg <= c_flag;    
                WHEN "0111" => Outs <= RCA_output; -- ADDC
                WHEN "1000" => Outs <= RCA_output; -- SUB
                WHEN "1001" => Outs <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(UNSIGNED(A) SLL to_integer(UNSIGNED(B(4 DOWNTO 0))));
                WHEN "1010" => Outs <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(A) SRL to_integer(UNSIGNED(B(4 DOWNTO 0))));
                WHEN "1011" => Outs <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(shift_right(SIGNED(A),to_integer(UNSIGNED(B(4 DOWNTO 0)))));
                WHEN OTHERS => Outs <= (OTHERS => '0');
            END CASE;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
END arch_ALU;
```

This ALU however is not that complex and don´t have that many operations but that functionality can easily be added. I hope the example code I have given you will help you.