# VHDL can't determine definition of operator "+"

Tags: vhdl

When I am trying to compile my code it has an error in the following part:

```
overflow <= input_a(15) + input_b(15);
```

I had declared the input_a and input_b as 15 bit vectors and the libraries that I am using are :

```
library ieee; 
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
```

So the error is :

```
Error (10327): VHDL error at alu16.vhd(45): can't determine definition of operator ""+"" -- found 0 possible definitions
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: A couple of us responded to your last question. Did you see that?

Comment: of course thank you . But I have another issue now

Answer (score 5):

If `input_a` and `input_b` are `std_logic_vector`, then `input_a(15)` and `input_b(15)` are `std_logic`, but VHDL does not have a `+` operator defined for `std_logic`, thus the error.

If you want to generate a result based on two `std_logic` values, you have the standard logical operators as `and`, `or`, `xor`, and `not` available, which will suffice.

Comment: Is there any other way to do what I am trying to do here ?

Comment: @N.Pipis There are two ways to generate overflow. If you have access to the carry in and the carry out for the MSB you can XOR them. See [Calculating Overflow Flag: Method 2](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt). The idea is predicated on you using carry in/out in full adders, in your [Making a 16-bit ALU using 1-bit ALUs - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274666/making-a-16-bit-alu-using-1-bit-alus) as Matthew indicated or see Calculating Overflow Flag: Method 1 for the other way. Simply adding the MSBs of a and b isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Try including the unsigned library...it worked for me!
I have the libraries listed and I could did the sum

```
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform arithmetic operations you should declare `signed`/`unsigned` signals instead of `bit_vector`/`std_logic_vector`.

Those last types can only be used with logical operations such as `and`/`or` ... because the compiler doesn't know whether you want your signal to be signed or unsigned.

When using signed/unsigned types you have to use the IEEE `numeric_std` package.

Answer (score -1):

Add this :
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
so you can use the operations + - ... with std_logic

Comment: No, that package should be avoided , [as they were deprecated many many years ago](http://insights.sigasi.com/tech/deprecated-ieee-libraries.html). With VHDL-2008, `numeric_std_unsigned` was introduced, if you REALLY want to do arithmetic using `std_logic_vector`. But better not to.