# Creating a 16-bit ALU from 16 1-bit ALUs (Structural code)

Tags: vhdl, alu

i have created the structural and the behavioral code for a 1-bit ALU,as well as a control circuit .The control circuit decides the operation that will be conducted between two variables : a,b .

Here is my behavioral part of the code :

```
 library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
package erotima2 is

-- AND2 declaration
 component myAND2
        port (outnotA,outnotB: in std_logic; outAND: out std_logic);
 end component;


-- OR2 declaration
  component myOR2          
       port (outnotA,outnotB: in std_logic; outOR: out std_logic);
 end component;

-- XOR2 declaration
  component myXOR2          
       port (outnotA,outnotB: in std_logic; outXOR: out std_logic);
 end component;

--fulladder declaration
  component fulladder     
            port(CarryIn,outnotA,outnotB: in std_logic; sum,CarryOut: out std_logic);
  end component;

--Ainvert declaration
  component notA        
            port(a: in std_logic; signala: std_logic_vector(0 downto 0); outnotA: out std_logic);
  end component;    

--Binvert declaration
  component notB                
           port(b: in std_logic; signalb: std_logic_vector(0 downto 0); outnotB: out std_logic);
  end component;

    --ControlCircuit declaration--
component ControlCircuit
    port (
            opcode : in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
            signala,signalb : out std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
            operation : out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
            CarryIn: out std_logic);

end component;

--mux4to1 declaration
    component mux4to1           
            port(outAND, outOR, sum, outXOR: in std_logic; operation: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0); Result: out std_logic);
    end component;

end package erotima2;   


--2 input AND gate
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
 entity myAND2 is
     port (outnotA,outnotB: in std_logic; outAND: out std_logic);
 end myAND2;
 architecture model_conc of myAND2 is
 begin
    outAND<= outnotA and outnotB;
 end model_conc;


 -- 2 input OR gate  
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
  entity myOR2 is
        port (outnotA,outnotB: in std_logic; outOR: out std_logic);
 end myOR2;
 architecture model_conc2 of myOR2 is
  begin
        outOR <= outnotA or outnotB;
 end model_conc2;     


--2 input XOR gate
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    entity myXOR2 is
        port(outnotA,outnotB: in std_logic; outXOR: out std_logic);
    end myXOR2;
    architecture model_conc3 of myXOR2 is
    begin 
    outXOR <= outnotA xor outnotB;
    end model_conc3;      

--3 input full adder      
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    entity fulladder is
        port(CarryIn,outnotA,outnotB: in std_logic; sum,CarryOut: out std_logic);
    end fulladder;
    architecture model_conc4 of fulladder is
    begin
    CarryOut <= (outnotB and CarryIn) or (outnotA and CarryIn) or (outnotA and outnotB);
    sum <= (outnotA and not outnotB and not CarryIn) or (not outnotA and outnotB and not CarryIn) or (not outnotA and not outnotB and CarryIn) or (outnotA and outnotB and CarryIn);
    end model_conc4;

--1 input notA
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    entity notA is
        port(a: in std_logic; signala:std_logic_vector(0 downto 0); outnotA: out std_logic);
    end notA;
    architecture model_conc6 of notA is
    begin
    with signala select
    outnotA <=  a when "0",
                        not a when others;
    end model_conc6;

--1 input notB    
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    entity notB is
        port(b: in std_logic; signalb: std_logic_vector(0 downto 0); outnotB: out std_logic);
    end notB;
    architecture model_conc5 of notB is
    begin
    with signalb select
    outnotB <=  b when "0",
                        not b when others;
    end model_conc5;


--4 input MUX 
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    entity mux4to1 is
        port(outAND, outOR, sum, outXOR: in std_logic; operation: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0); Result: out std_logic);
    end mux4to1;
    architecture model_conc7 of mux4to1 is
    begin
    with operation select
        Result<= outAND when "00",
                 outOR  when "01",
              sum    when "10",
                   outXOR when OTHERS;
    end model_conc7 ;
```

The behavioral part defines the logic gates of AND,OR,XOR,  a full adder for numerical addition and substraction. It also contains a 4-to-1 multiplexer that chooses (depending on the value of the "operation" variable) which operation the alu will do. Lastly there is a function that inverts the variables in order to be more efficient with our logic gate usage( using the DeMorgan theorem so we don't have to create a NOR gate). The control unit initializes the variable inputs, as well as the carryIn variable of the full adder, depending on the variable "opcode". [A board with every possible combination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exHZ1.png)
Next is the Control Circuit part of the code, which implements the previous board.

```
`     
 library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity ControlCircuit is 
    port (
            opcode      :in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
            signala, signalb : out  std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
            operation : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
            CarryIn : out std_logic);               
end ControlCircuit;

architecture model_conc9 of ControlCircuit is   
--signal outAND,outOR,outXOR,sum,outnotA,outnotB : std_logic;
--signal operation : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);  
begin
 process(opcode)
 begin

case opcode is 

    --AND--
    when "000"=>
        operation <= "00";
        signala   <= "0";
        signalb      <= "0";
        CarryIn  <= '0';

    --OR--
    when "001" =>
        operation <= "01";
        signala   <= "0";
        signalb      <= "0";
        CarryIn  <= '0';

    --ADD--         
    when "011" =>
        operation <= "10";
        signala   <= "0";
        signalb      <= "0";
        CarryIn  <= '0';

    --SUB--
    when "010" =>
        operation <= "10";
        signala   <= "0";
        signalb      <="1";
        CarryIn  <= '1';

    --NOR--
    when "101"=>
        operation <= "00";
        signala   <= "1";
        signalb      <= "1";
        CarryIn  <= '0';

    --xor
    when "100" =>
        operation <= "11";
        signala   <= "0";
        signalb      <= "0";
        CarryIn  <= '0';

    --Adiafores times--
when others =>
        operation <= "00";
        signala   <= "0";
        signalb      <= "0";
        CarryIn  <= '0';
    end case;
    end process;
end model_conc9;

        `
```

Lastly here is the code that uses all the previous parts and [and an RTL diagram that shows the code's result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYHCw.png)

```
  library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.erotima2.all;

entity structural is 
    port (a,b: in std_logic;
            opcode : in std_logic_vector ( 2 downto 0);
            Result,CarryOut : out std_logic);
end structural;

architecture alu of structural is 
    signal outAND,outOR,outXOR,sum,outnotA,outnotB,CarryIn : std_logic;
    signal signala,signalb : std_logic_vector (0 downto 0);
    signal operation : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
begin 

u0 : myAND2 port map (outnotA,outnotB,outAND);
u1 : myOR2 port map (outnotA,outnotB,outOR);
u2 : myXOR2 port map (outnotA,outnotB,outXOR);
u3 : fulladder port map (CarryIn,outnotA,outnotB,sum,CarryOut);
u4 : notA port map (a,signala,outnotA);
u5 : notB port map (b,signalb,outnotB);
u6 : mux4to1 port map (outAND, outOR,sum, outXOR, operation, Result );
u8 : ControlCircuit port map(opcode,signala,signalb,operation,CarryIn);
end alu;
```

Now for the tough part, i need to use the 1-bit ALU 16 times as a component, to create a 16-bit ALU. It is important to keep the control circuit independent from the rest of the code. I have tried using an std_logic_vector ( 15 downto 0) but it did not work and i would like to use the previous code segments as a component. Can anyone give any tips or ideas that will help connect 16 1-bit ALUs to a complete 16-bit ALU? Thanks in advance for those who read this massive wall of text.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/). You post so much code, without giving a clear problem statement. Your single question seems to be "Can anyone give any tips or ideas that will help connect 16 1-bit ALUs to a complete 16-bit ALU?". The rest doesn't seem necessary. What have you tried already, and where did it fail?

Comment: p.s. there are many mistakes in the code.... did you test it at all? Or just doing it trial-and-error?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and sorry for posting too much code. I tested the code and it worked as intended for the 1-bit calculations part (i am a beginner in this language so i don't know how many mistakes my code has). To phrase my question more clearly, what i'm trying to do is use the already created 1-bit ALU to create a 16bit ALU that does calculations between two 16bit variables. What i tried to do is use "std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)" to all elements of the code except for the Control Circuit that needs only one use to determine the calculation between the variables (AND, OR, ADD etc)

Comment: This did not work, which i believe is a mistake of attaching the Control Circuit code into the part which i need to repeat. So what i'm trying to understand is whether the way i tried to implement the solution was right but the excecution was wrong, or it was completely wrong right from the beginning. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a 16-bit ALU using 1-bit ALUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274666/making-a-16-bit-alu-using-1-bit-alus), [Making a 4-bit ALU from several 1-bit ALUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025962/making-a-4-bit-alu-from-several-1-bit-alus), and many others found using search

Comment: Well, one of the problems is already: how are you going to connect the `CarryOut` to the next `structural`? You code is pretty weird. Inverting all signals before connecting them to the next logic gate. Is this for a course in VHDL? In that case I suggest you looking up ALU examples on the internet, because your professor will not like this code...

Comment: Yes  i understand that my code is weird but we were intsructed to invert the inputs according to ![this diagram](https://imgur.com/a/a8ej40p) . As for the duplicate post, i checked before posting and they were implemented only structurally, while in my case i need to write the behavioral part too.

Comment: Maybe you should provide all the instructions you were given. The RTL diagram doesn't match the1bit alu diagram you were given (there's no carry in, which is used in the LSB to Add 1 for subtraction, there's added inversion controls).  Make a structural entity to match the 1 bit alu diagram and use that as a basis. Don't use length1 std_logic_vector values. You'll find the control naturally falls outside and can be used for any size alu. Include [this diagram](https://imgur.com/a/a8ej40p) in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recent comment

> Yes i understand that my code is weird but we were intsructed to invert the inputs according to [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PU7y.jpg) . As for the duplicate post, i checked before posting and they were implemented only structurally, while in my case i need to write the behavioral part too.

[image: 1 bit alu diagram]

Explains the issue, misspellings aside. You'll notice your architecture structural of entity structural doesn't match the signals shown on the above 1 bit alu diagram which doesn't contain an instantiated ControlCircuit.

If you were to provide a design unit that matched the above diagram you can hook up the 1 bit alu carry chain while deriving the carryin for the lsb from the control block which provides a + 1 and inversion for subtraction:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity alu_16_bit is
    port (
        a:          in  std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
        b:          in  std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
        opcode:     in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        result:     out std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
        carryout:   out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of alu_16_bit is
    component alu_1_bit is
        port (
            a:          in  std_logic;
            b:          in  std_logic;
            ainvert:    in  std_logic;
            binvert:    in  std_logic;
            carryin:    in  std_logic;
            operation:  in  std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
            result:     out std_logic;
            carryout:   out std_logic
        );
    end component;
    component controlcircuit is
        port (
            opcode:     in  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
            ainvert:    out std_logic;
            binvert:    out std_logic;
            operation:  out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
            carryin:    out std_logic  -- invert a or b, add + 1 for subtract
        );
    end component;

    signal ainvert:     std_logic;
    signal binvert:     std_logic;
    signal operation:   std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    signal carry:       std_logic_vector (16 downto 0);
begin

CONTROL_CIRCUIT:
    controlcircuit
        port map (
            opcode => opcode,
            ainvert => ainvert,
            binvert => binvert,
            operation => operation,
            carryin => carry(0)   -- for + 1 durring subtract
        );

GEN_ALU:
    for i in 0 to 15 generate
ALU:
        alu_1_bit
            port map (
                a => a(i),
                b => b(i),
                ainvert => ainvert,
                binvert => binvert,
                carryin => carry(i),
                operation => operation,
                result => result(i),
                carryout => carry(i + 1) 
            );
    end generate;

    carryout <= carry(16) when operation = "10" else '0';

end architecture;
```

This represents moving ControlCircuit out of structural - only one copy is needed, renaming structural alu_1_bit and making the ports match.

There's a new top level alu_16_bit containing a single instance of ControlCircuit along with sixteen instances of alu_1_bit elaborated from the generate statement using the generate parameter `i` to index into arrays values for connections.

This design has been behaviorally implemented independently using the Opcode table you provided the link to:

[image: Opcode Table]

as well as an independent fulladder used in alu_1_bit and appears functional.

This implies your design units haven't been validated.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer! I completely understood what i've been doing wrong all this time. Thank you very much!